# switch cases with push method discord.js v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Versions - Discord.js@v12.5.3 | Node v14.17.3

The problem is with switch cases. We have two questions after the user has had answered them bot sends a message that the user has to try again, no matter if the user has typed the right answer.
If the user has typed the wrong answer then the bot ignores it and continues to ask questions from the list. After the list is empty he sends a message to the channel that the application has been sent and that the user had typed the wrong answer.

I know the code isn't short, but please have a look. Any help would help, thanks!

```
 const { Client, Message, MessageEmberd, MessageEmbed, ReactionCollector } = require('discord.js');
const button = require('./button');

module.exports = {
    name: 'apply',
    /**
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {Message} message
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, message, args) => {

        
        let index = 1;

        const Moduliai = [
            `${index++}) lt?`,
            `it?`
            
        ];


        let collectCounter = 0;
        let endCounter = 0;

        const filter = (m) => m.author.id === message.author.id;

        const appsChannel = client.channels.cache.get('904003816876285973');

        const appStart = await message.channel.send(Moduliai[collectCounter++]);
        const channel = appStart.channel;

        const collector = channel.createMessageCollector(filter);


        const answers = [];

        const geraFunkcija = (expr) => {
            switch (expr) {
              case "lt":
                  case "Lietuvių":
                      case "Lietuviu":
                          message.channel.send('lt')
                          break;
              case "it":
                  case "Info":
                      case "informacinės":
                          case "informacinių":
                              case "informaciniu tech":
                                  case "informaciniu technologiju":
                                      case "informacinių technologijų":
                                          message.channel.send('it')
                                          break;
              default:
                  console.log('Try again')
                    message.channel.send('wrong answer, try again');
                    channel.send(Moduliai[collectCounter-1]);
                    break;
            }}


        collector.on("collect", async (m) => {
            if(collectCounter < Moduliai.length) {
                await channel.send(Moduliai[collectCounter++])
                
                console.log(`${m.content}`)
            } else {
                message.reply('application was sent.')
                collector.stop("fulfilled");
            }
        });

        // collector.on("collect", async (collected) => {
        //     if(collectCounter < Moduliai.length) {
        //         await channel.send(Moduliai[collectCounter++])
        //         geraFunkcija(collected[index-1]);
        //     } else {
        //         message.reply('aplikacija buvo išsiųsta.')
        //         collector.stop("fulfilled");
        //     }
        // });

        collector.on('end', async (collected, reason) => {
            console.log(`${collected.size}`)
            geraFunkcija(collected[index-1]);
            if(reason === "fulfilled") {
                collected.map((msg) => {
                //   geraFunkcija(msg.content);
                //   answers.push(msg.content);
                  answers.push(msg.content);
                //   return msg.content;
                })
      
              
              console.log(answers);

              const answersStep = collected.map((msg) => {
                return `${Moduliai[endCounter++]}\n-> ${answers}`;
              })

          appsChannel.send(
            new MessageEmbed()
                .setAuthor(message.author.tag, 
                message.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true})
                )
                .setTitle('New Application')
                .setDescription(answersStep)
                .setTimestamp()
            ).then(sent => {
                sent.react("✅")
                sent.react("❌")
            });

            client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if(reaction.message.channel.id === "904003816876285973") {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && user.id === message.guild.ownerID) {
                    for (let i=0; i<2; i++) {
                        geraFunkcija(answers[i].toLowerCase())
                    }
                } if (reaction.message.channel.id === "904003816876285973") {
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === '❌' && user.id === message.guild.ownerID) {
                        message.reply('your application was cancelled.')
                    }

                }
                }
            })
        }
    });
}};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code runs the switch statement function (further called `sFunction`)  on the `end` event and you pass just one of the answers to it from the `collected`, which is `Map` and you can't interpret it as an `Array`, so actually you don't even pass an answer but an `undefined` value to `sFunction`, that's why you get dropped to `default` case.

What I suggest doing is removing `sFunction` from `end` event and putting it on `collect` event. Then you would pass `m.content` to the `sFunction` and you should be good to go.